# Azure App Gateway - Rewrite invalid HTTP headers

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

App gateway has an uncofigurable nginx option `ignore_invalid_headers`, which [defaults to true](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/28045).

I've got a header being passed in as `my.custom.key` which isn't a valid header format, to get around the restriction I'm trying to add a rewrite rule to convert the invalid header, into a valid one (i.e. `X-My-Custom-Key`), but having any luck.

Are the invalid headers stripped before the rewrite rules are applied by app gateway, and if so is there another workaround (besides just supplying the correctly formatted header)?

[image]

Comment: Check this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-portal) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-url-portal)

Comment: Yeah don't think either of those apply, thanks though

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this? I have the same problem.